# Start session for second time or?

Tags: php, session-variables

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   ...
?>

<?php 
   session_start();
?>
```

If I have some php script like this one. My question is should I escape to start session for second time or it is necessary?

Comment: The second call should throw a notice or warning. I can't think of a scenario when it could ever be necessary

Comment: As Pekka said, you should get a warning of "Session already started. Cannot start session" or something like that. If you don't want to change the code, might use if(session_id () =='') {session_start();}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not to start it again.
As of now, calling session_start() while the session has already been started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.

Comment: As it is written in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php